# How to structure Angularjs/Leaflet/Node.js Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I am working on Web app that analyze public transportation in real-time. 
I build an interactive map dashboard. 
I use : 
- Node.Js: for backend processing.
- Angularjs & Leaflet: to work on the front end data visualization.

I'd like reorganize my project, but I couldn't find a convenient structure. 
I took a look at angular-seed, the official starting point for AngularJS apps. The "app" directory contains the following structure:

```
css/
img/
js/
   app.js
   controllers.js
   directives.js
   filters.js
   services.js
lib/
partials/
```

Another structuring found on `[ng-boilerplate][1]` repo

```
build/
src/
app/
assets/
components/
less/
testacular/ (or karma/)
vendor/
    Grunfile.js
    module.prefix
    module.suffix
    package.json
```

I found this [Angular Leaflet App Skeleton](https://github.com/jlongnbt/angular-leaflet-skeleton), it could be a good start, but how can I add Node.Js
I found also two great articles :

- [Angular App Structuring Guidelines](http://www.johnpapa.net/angular-app-structuring-guidelines/)
- [AngularJS Best Practices: I’ve Been Doing It Wrong! Part 1 of 3](http://www.artandlogic.com/blog/2013/05/ive-been-doing-it-wrong-part-1-of-3/)

Do you recommend using angular-leaflet-directive and Node.js, or build Angularjs/Leaflet/Node.js project ?

What is the best way to structure my project in this case ?

Comment: Check out this article: [The case for separating front- and back-end](http://dontpanic.42.nl/2014/10/the-case-for-separating-front-and-back.html)

Answer (score 2):

It may be better to not have Angular and NodeJS code in the same project. Let your NodeJS project be a pure JSON API. The Angular project can be a client project.

You can serve the Angular code from an Apache or CGI server and run your Express server for the NodeJS.